# How do I convert from NSString to NSDate using NSDateFormater

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this string: `2012-01-12T21:01:00` and this code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate* arrivalTime=[df dateFromString:field_arrival_time];
```

But it returns `nil`. What date format should I use to parse this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string `2012-01-12T21:01:00` contains the literal `T` (At least I believe it's a literal, it doesn't appear to signify a timezone). You must include this in your date format.

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"];
```

Note the lack of the  `a` in the date format, using it will require your input string to use AM or PM preceded by a white space. For more information on special characters with [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) take a look at the [Date Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) paying extra attention to the **Fixed Formats**.

Edit: Your input string does not specify a timezone, it will probably be interpreted as UTC and be localized to the timezone of your machine when you output it through `NSLog()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot on your string but never get result. only nil shows on console. but when i remove character "T" from your string it gives perfect result.

```
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"2012-01-12 21:01:00"];
NSLog(@"date %@", date);
NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *s = [f2 stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"S %@", s);
/// OutPut : S 12-01-2012
```